# Dimension of extension of scalars

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The context is this: Let's say $X$ is an affine scheme of finite type over a field $k$. Then if $K$ is a field extension of $k$, you can consider the affine scheme $X_K$. Are the dimensions of $X$ and $X_K$ equal?

Comment: You are asking if a finite type $k$-algebra $A$ has the same Krull dimension as $A\otimes _k K$ for some extension $K/k$...

Comment: Yes...I'm guessing that the dimensions should be equal because I'm just extending scalars, but I don't know how to prove that from the definition of Krull dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=\mathcal O(X)$ be the  ring of $X$. [Noether's normalization lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma) says that there is an inclusion $k[T_1,\cdots,T_d]\subset A$ with $d= \dim A=\dim X$ and $A$ finite and thus integral  over $k[T_1,\cdots,T_d]$ .
 Since $K$ is flat over $k$, tensoring by $K$ over $k$ yields a new inclusion: $$K[T_1,\cdots,T_d]=k[T_1,\cdots,T_d]\otimes _k K\subset A\otimes_k K$$ But this inclusion is still integral,  so that  $\dim A\otimes_k K=\dim K[T_1,\cdots,T_d]=d$ and finally $\dim X_K=\dim A\otimes_k K=d=\dim X$, as desired.
[I have used that in an integral inclusion of rings $A\subset B$ one has $\dim A=\dim B$]

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to learn the theory of algebraic groups over an arbitrary field, whereas before I had read more elementary books where they work with the rational points over an algebraically closed field (essentially with matrices), so now I'm "relearning" the whole theory in the scheme-theoretic way.

Comment: Good luck in your relearning, dear CoffeeBliss.